# How to deploy magepack bundling on production

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy, deployment, magento2-cloud, jsbundling

magento.app.yaml when i am deploying on cloud error is occur
W: /etc/platform/bletrhxa5fb2a_stg/auto_post_deploy.sh: 3: /etc/platform/bletrhxa5fb2a_stg/auto_post_deploy.sh: magepack: not found

In Build hooks that is the script
hooks:
build: |
set -e
composer install
unset NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
nvm install --lts=erbium
npm config set puppeteer_skip_chromium_download true -g
# Install Gulp CLI and magepack globally in one command
npm install -g gulp-cli

```
# Run npm commands in the specific design folder
(cd ./app/design/frontend/Fluid/blank/ &&  npm install && gulp)

# Install magepack globally in one command
npm install -g magepack
php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools run scenario/build/generate.xml
php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools run scenario/build/transfer.xml
```

deploy: |
php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools run scenario/deploy.xml

```
# Bundle Magepack after static content deployment
magepack bundle
```

please suggest me what i do.?